# Поддерживает ли Qt яп С

Tags: c, qt

Поддерживает ли Qt язык программирования Си ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короткий ответ: **нет**.
Если нужен комплексный инструментарий GUI для `C`, вы можете использовать `GTK+`.
Чтобы использовать `Qt`, у вас должен быть компилятор `C++`.
Но это не значит, что «логика приложения» не может быть записана на `C`, скомпилирована с компилятором `C` и тщательно связана с частью `C++` (GUI с Qt). Эта прикладная логика может быть общей, связываться с другими исполняемыми файлами (pure-C, смешанные C / C ++ и т.д.).
Все зависит от того, что вам нужно. `Qt` отлично подходит для `C++`, и это хорошая причина для решения использовать `C++` для конкретного проекта, даже если вы все еще хотите сохранить части на `C`.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728509/does-qt-have-a-c-interface)